[React Native][expo-camera] Preview Issue
May I know how can I make a preview screen of 4:3, and make sure the captured image is just the same as the preview. I have tried to set aspect ratio on the CameraView, but the image captured is not the same as the preview.
<CameraView
  style={{
    width: '100%,
    aspectRatio: 4 / 3,
  }}
  facing={'back'}
  ref={cameraRef}
/>

